# Sending plain text to controller mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How to send plain text to a controller

```
public ActionResult mappingNodes(string model) {
    var test = model;
    return Json(new { foo = "bar"});
}
```

via post method:

```
 $http.post("/msm/test/mappingNodes", postModel, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}})
```

If I choose for the `postModel` a string like "abc" or `'{model : "abc"}'` I get null on controller side.

If I change the parameter `Content-Type` to `application/jason` I get "abc" on controller side if the `postModel` is set to `'{model : "abc"}'` if the `postModel` is set to "abc" I get error status Code 500 in my errorCallback function.

Answer (score 1):

You should send data to controller in javascript array, like this:

```
$http.post("/msm/test/mappingNodes", { model : postModel }, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}})
```

Note, that name of parameter in your controller `model`, must match key `model` in javascript array.

Comment: I dont know if `'Content-Type': 'text/plain'` in your suggestion is the right parameter. In your case I would choose ` 'Content-Type': 'application/json'` , because your object `{ model : postModel }` is of type  json not plain text.

Comment: I don't know what are you using for sending POST requests, but with jquery I do it like this `var request = $.ajax({ url: 'myurl',
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: { someId: id },
            datatype: "json"
        })
        request.done(function (data) {
            //your code
            })
        })`
where `dataType` is the type of data that you're expecting back from the server.
And it works well with my controller `[HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> MyController(string someId)`

Answer (score 0):

You can just append the text with the server URL.

Like this:

```
$http.post("/msm/test/mappingNodes/yourtext", postModel, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}})
```

Or if the value is in a variable:

```
$http.post("/msm/test/mappingNodes/" + value, postModel, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}})
```

Comment: If I try your  suggestion and set `postModel` to '{model: "{\"abc\":\"test\"}"}' I got also the status code 500 in my errorCallback.

Answer (score 0):

Pass through the query string (url encoded):

```
$http.post("/msm/test/mappingNodes?postModel=" + postModel)
```

Or include it in the post data:

```
$http.post("/msm/test/mappingNodes", { postModel: "myvalue" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your action with `[FromBody]` parameter attribute

```
public ActionResult mappingNodes([FromBody]string model) {
    var test = model;
    return Json(new { foo = "bar"});
}
```

Here is an example client request.

```
POST http://localhost:5076/msm/test/mappingNodes HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:5076
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 5

"abc"
```

Comment: I tried it via ` $http.post("/msm/test/mappingNodes", "abc", { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' } })` but the variable `model` in the controler is null.

Comment: try same request but with Content-Type as application/jason and see if that makes a difference

Comment: I get the same result like I described in my start post `erro code 500`.